# How to set a function as the onInput$ property of an input in Qwik

Tags: typescript, qwik

I'm trying to pass a function to the `onInput$` property of an `input` element in Qwik but it does not work.

My code is the following:

```
function onInput(ev: Event) {
  //Do something
}

<input onInput$={handleInput} />
```

And i'm getting the following error:

```
Internal server error: Code(25): Invalid JSXNode type. It must be either a function or a string.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your function using `$()`, like this:

```
const onInput = $((ev: Event) => {
  //Do something
});
```

You will also have to import the `$()` function:

```
import { $ } from "@builder.io/qwik";
```